# Can a single core processor be MIMD?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

I was wondering for if a single core processor can be MIMD? or MISD? or SIMD?
I thought MIMD's requirement is multicore, but I am not sure about this

Comment: In part, this depends in interpretation. Do the "common bit-wise boolean operations" operate on just two *bit vectors*, or on many independent pairs of bits according to operand size? When you place, say, 5-bit values *a, b* in one 32-bit word *x* as $x = a * 2^{2*5} +b$, similarly *c, d* in *y*, do $s = x+y$ (results in 5+1 bits each from 0 and 2*5 up, resp.), $p = x * y$ (results in 10 bits each from 0 and 2*2*5) operate on single data or multiple?

Comment: You’d have to read the exact definition of the “MI” part. No reason that a single core with more than one short vector instruction per cycle isn’t MIMD.